# Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-whisper

I had this error while trying to install openai-whisper. With this command:
pip install openai-whisper

I'm facing issue with some errors

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\PCM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xp6bsqi1\numba_793bc13dbcb4462c9ea61f15c6419797\setup.py", line 51, in <module>
          _guard_py_ver()
        File "C:\Users\PCM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xp6bsqi1\numba_793bc13dbcb4462c9ea61f15c6419797\setup.py", line 48, in _guard_py_ver
          raise RuntimeError(msg.format(cur_py, min_py, max_py))
      RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.8,<3.12 are supported.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

i just need to install this lib to start my project

Comment: "RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.8,<3.12 are supported."

Answer (score 0):

PyPi states:

> We used Python 3.9.9 and PyTorch 1.10.1 to train and test our models, but the codebase is expected to be compatible with Python 3.8-3.11 and recent PyTorch versions.

This explains your error message `RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.8,<3.12 are supported.`

You can downgrade to a supported Python version to fix this error. Visit https://pypi.org/project/openai-whisper/ for more information.